# Key in v-for loop?

Tags: vuejs3

The [docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/key-attribute.html#with-template-v-for) say:

In Vue 3.x, the key should be placed on the  tag instead.

```
<template v-for="item in list" :key="item.id">
  <div>...</div>
  <span>...</span>
</template>
```

But I wish to use the index as my key, so I do:

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in props.items" :key="index">
```

But I get the warning `index is declared but never read`.

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of a key is to be able to identify items regardless of where they are in the list. Since index isn't intrinsic to the item, it doesn't achieve this. You can achieve the same effect as using index as the key by just not declaring the key entirely, but this isn't recommended:
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key